# How can I reduce executed queries in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, performance, model, attributes

I have about 6 custom attributes on my model, and in my blade view, I loop through filtered models and use these attributes in some if-else statements, but it takes a lot of time to render, as it executes a lot of queries.

Here is an example of an attribute I have.

```php
/**
 * Determine if an invoice is due.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getInvoiceDueAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->invoice_frequency) {
        return $this->finished && (!$this->invoiced || $this->outgoing_invoices()->whereNull('invoice_number')->count() > 0);
    }

    $last_invoice = $this->outgoing_invoices()
        ->where('invoiceable', true)
        ->latest()
        ->first();

    return ($last_invoice ? $last_invoice->created_at : $this->created_at)
        ->startOfMonth()->addMonth($this->invoice_frequency)->isPast();
}
```

Blade:

```xml
@foreach($building->projects as $project)
    ...
    <td class="text-center text-nowrap align-middle">
        <a href="{{ route('outgoing-invoices.indexPre', ['project' => $project->id]) }}"
           class="btn btn-sm btn-{{ $project->invoice_state_color }} @cannot ('Invoice view') disabled @endcannot">
            @if ($project->invoice_ok)
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp; Számlázva
            @elseif ($project->invoice_in_progress)
                <i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i>&nbsp; Folyamatban
            @elseif ($project->invoice_due)
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp; Számlázatlan
            @else
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp; Nem esedékes
            @endif
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center text-nowrap align-middle">
        @if ($project->invoice_with_project_id)
            Havi riportban
        @else
            <a href="{{ route('outgoing-invoices.index', ['project' => $project->id]) }}"
               class="btn btn-sm btn-{{ $project->payment_state_color }} @cannot ('Invoice view') disabled @endcannot">
                @if ($project->payment_ok)
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp; Nincs fizetetlen számla
                @elseif (is_null($project->payment_ok))
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp; Nem esedékes
                @else
                    <i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i>&nbsp; Folyamatban
                @endif
            </a>
        @endif
    </td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

To be clear, **my goal is to improve performance** by reducing queries or any other way.

*I also accept best-practice advice for any part of my code.* Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look into eager loading. In both spots where you call `$this->outgoing_invoices()`, you can eager load that via a relationship, like `public function nullInvoices()` and `public function lastInvoice()`, then `Invoices::with(['nullInvoices', 'lastInvoice']) ...`, and `$this->nullInvoice->count()` and `$lastInvoice = $this->lastInvoice`, etc etc. That would cut down on 2 queries per loaded invoice, which can add up quite quickly.

Comment: May i see your blade loop too ?

Comment: I added my loop.